# NodeJS + Socket.io Connection event handler not being called successfully?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, socket.io

I have the following code in a file called server.js, and index.html

For some reason, the io.on('connection') part is not calling the console.log method in its callback when I navigate to my server in my web browser.

Check the code below, it speaks for itself.
**server.js**

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    io = require('socket.io')(app.Server),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    apiRouter = require('./app/routes/api.js');

//Clears Node Console.
process.stdout.write('\033c');
console.log('Server starting!');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(apiRouter);
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.use('*', function(req, res, next) {
    //All requests return single page angular application.
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});

mongoose.connect('localhost', 'triviaattack', function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('An error occured when connecting to the MongoDB Database');
        throw err;
    }
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('client connected via socket'); //This is the line that isn't being called
});

app.listen(1337, function() {
    console.log('Server started successfully @ ' + Date());
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./app/app.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.5.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io();
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
        {{message}}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.

Had to change server.js to the following, notice the new http variable near the top.  Still kind of curious as to why just passing in app.Server wasn't working in my original post...oh well.

```
var app = require('express')(),
    http = require('http').Server(app),
    io = require('socket.io')(http),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    apiRouter = require('./app/routes/api.js');

//Clears Node Console.
process.stdout.write('\033c');
console.log('Server starting!');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(apiRouter);

app.use('*', function(req, res, next) {
    //All requests return single page angular application.
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});

mongoose.connect('localhost', 'triviaattack', function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('An error occured when connecting to the MongoDB Database');
        throw err;
    }
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('client connected via socket');
});

http.listen(1337, function() {
    console.log('Server started successfully @ ' + Date());
});
```